# Fetching from Firestore into SfDataGrid

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, datatable

Can you kindly share with me an example of SfDatagrid connected to Firestore, using Flutter? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you have a few questions that need research:
- How to load data from Firestore into a Flutter app
- How to transform data into table rows
- How to use SfDatagrid API to build table in Flutter

Comment: Thank you David, I do know how to retrieve from Firestore, I know how to populate the Listview.builder as well. 

But this SFDatagrid is chalenging to me. Can I share part of my code with you please. I'd really be grateful if you can assist. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,
this is based of an example found on the Syncfusion site:
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12766/how-to-load-data-from-firebase-to-flutter-datatable-sfdatagrid
this example uses the realtime database but you just need to fill in the right code to make it work for firestore, so instead of:

```
  getDataFromDatabase() async {
    var value = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    var getValue = await value.child('DataGridEmployeeCollection').once();
    return getValue;
  }
```

you initialize:

```
 FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _userStream =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').snapshots();
```

I use a stream because I want my data to update realtime.
and then follow the example trough it should look like this:

UserData source:

```
class UserDataSource extends DataGridSource {
  UserDataSource(this._currentUserInfo) {
    _buildDataRow();
  }

  List<DataGridRow> users = [];
  List<CurrentUserInfo> _currentUserInfo;

  void _buildDataRow() {
    users = _currentUserInfo
        .map<DataGridRow>((e) => DataGridRow(
              cells: [
                DataGridCell<String>(
                  columnName: "Uid",
                  value: e.Uid,
                ),
                DataGridCell<String>(
                  columnName: "Name",
                  value: e.Name,
                ),
                DataGridCell(
                  columnName: "Surname",
                  value: e.Surname,
                ),
                DataGridCell(
                  columnName: "Role",
                  value: e.UserRole,
                ),
                DataGridCell(
                  columnName: "City",
                  value: e.City,
                ),
              ],
            ))
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => users;

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter buildRow(
    DataGridRow row,
  ) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((e) {
      return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(e.value.toString()),
      );
    }).toList());
  }
}
```

```
class _UserIndexState extends State<UserIndex> {
  @override
  late UserDataSource userDataSource;
  late List<CurrentUserInfo> UserData = [];
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _userStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').snapshots();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseWidget(child: Center(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _userStream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
          UserData.clear();
          snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
            UserData.add(
                CurrentUserInfo.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
          });

          userDataSource = UserDataSource(UserData);
          return SfDataGrid(
            columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.fill,
            source: userDataSource,
            columns: <GridColumn>[
              GridColumn(
                columnName: "Uid",
                label: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    'ID',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              //make gridcollumns for Name Surname role and city
              GridColumn(
                columnName: "Name",
                label: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    'Name',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GridColumn(
                columnName: "Surname",
                label: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    'Surname',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GridColumn(
                columnName: "Role",
                label: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    'Role',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GridColumn(
                columnName: "City",
                label: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    'City',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    ),);
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?